# MongoDB: Return deeply nested document from it's id regardless of level

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection consisting of documents that are made up of an id, name and an array of items; the array in each document is supposed to nest other documents of the same structure when applicable, and there is no limit to how many nested arrays of documents there are (nested documents can also have nested documents).

Using the MongoClient package, I'm trying to query my collection and return a document based on it's id, regardless of it's location in the data (be it at the top level or 3 levels down).

So far I can return any top level data okay, but my query is not finding any nested data. I've seen similar questions where the data structure is limited and consistent, but as my data is dynamic and multi-layered, I haven't find a solution that fits this particular issue.

Here's my data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "Test 3",
        "items": []
      },
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "name": "Test 4",
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": 6,
            "name": "Test 6",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "Test 5",
    "items": []
  }
]
```

Here's my Mongo query:

```
MongoClient.connect(connString, function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('items');
    collection.findOne({_id: ObjectID("4")}, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    db.close();
});
```

And result is *intended* to return the following, but returns null instead:

```
{
  "_id": 4,
  "name": "Test 4",
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": 6,
      "name": "Test 6",
      "items": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone share a solution as to how I can retrieve my data as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to query an infinate amount of document of documents due to the change of properties at each level. See Query Selectors (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors) for a list of selectors that can be used.

However if it's possbile to limit or give a depth limit on the items then you could use a query such as:-

```
db.col.find( {$or: [ { "_id" : id }, { "items._id" : id }, { "items.items._id" : id }, { "items.items.items._id" : id } ] } );
```

If it's not possible to give a depth limit I'd advise re-modeling the document in to something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Test 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Test 3",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "name": "Test 6",
    "parentId": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "Test 4",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Test 2",
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "Test 5",
  }
]
```

Then you could do a simple find by _id query:

```
> db.collection.find({_id: 4})
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Test 4", "parentId" : 2 }
```

If you also need to retain the document structure of the query you can use the `$graphLookup` aggregation stage.